# Ajax jQuery call not completing and returning string

Tags: jquery, ajax

I cant get the ajax running, as the test string doesnt show in the html.
The server works fine and the jQuery is up to date.
The code seems to be able to register the click and prevent the default behaviour, but it doesnt complete the ajax call.

```
//// index.php ////

<a id='id' href=''>Test</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#id').click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax(
        {                                      
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax.php',
            data:'test',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(d)
            {
                $('#id').html(d.msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

//// ajax.php ////

<?php

class ajax
{
    function test()
    {

        $t = array();
        $t['msg'] = 'Test';
        return  json_encode($t);
    }
}

$ajax = new ajax;
echo $ajax->test();

?>
```

Comment: I think the problem is in your function test(): your returning an empty array $t. So change the second line from $return['msg'] = 'Test'; to $t['msg'] = 'Test';. Assuming that the general Ajax call works finde, otherwise more information about what the ajax call returns would be great.

Comment: I made an edit regarding that part, I misstyped. Could you please specify what information you would find useful. The above is all the code in ajax.php.

Comment: Have you called the php file itself in the browser? Does it return the right result? If yes, what shows your browser's console when calling the ajax function in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `url:'ajax.php',`. I entered the wrong file path, despite checking it numerous times...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class ajax
{
    function test()
    {

        $t = array();
        $t['msg'] = 'Test';
        return  json_encode($t);
    }
}

$ajax = new ajax;
echo $ajax->test();

?>
```

You're returning an empty array, because you're not filling your $t array with any value. Change this, than it should work fine. Otherwise try calling your php in the browser itself and see what it returns.

Comment: The php file calls fine: {"msg":"Test"}

Comment: And what does your browser's console say, when you're executing the JS code?